# How to keep smooth lighting behavior with plotly mesh3d when triangle face vertex order is different?

Tags: plotly, mesh, plotly-python

I am plotting a triangle mesh. I expect the shading from one face to the next to be smooth; sometimes it is and sometimes its not. It seems to be dependent on the order of the vertices that  define the triangle.

**How can I make the ordering of the triangle vertices produce a smooth mesh?**

Here is a contrived example  where I changed the ordering of one of the triangle vertices and it causes  the shading to be different. Note: these define the same triangle the vertices are just ordered differently, (a,c,b) vs (b, c, a).

The plot on the left is what I want and the one of the right has the shading issue. I have tried [flatshading](https://plotly.com/python/reference/#mesh3d) however on larger meshes it doesn't look right. I have also tried sorting the triangle vertex indices (seems to be random shading).

[image]

Here is the code to produce the plot.

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

t1 = [0, 3, 1]
t2 = [0, 1, 2]
t2_alt = [0, 2, 1]  # same as t2 but different order
t3 = [1, 3, 2]

pts = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [0, 1, 0, 2],
    'y': [0, 1, 2, 1],
    'z': [0, 0, 1, 0],
})

surf1 = pd.DataFrame([t1, t2, t3], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
surf2 = pd.DataFrame([t1, t2_alt, t3], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, specs=[[{'type': 'mesh3d'}, {'type': 'mesh3d'}]])

fig.add_trace(go.Mesh3d(
        x=pts.x, y=pts.y, z=pts.z,
        i=surf1.b, j=surf1.a, k=surf1.c,
        color='blue'
    ), row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Mesh3d(
        x=pts.x, y=pts.y, z=pts.z,
        i=surf2.b, j=surf2.a, k=surf2.c,
        color='blue'
    ), row=1, col=2)

fig.show()
```

Comment: There is a [response](https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-make-3d-medical-images-more-contrast/68269/2) in the plotly community highlighting mesh3d. I'm not sure how well this fits your challenge, but it may be helpful.